# [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I resolve this error message :

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "drawer"

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-header bordered class="bg-grey-11">
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-btn

          @click="drawer = !drawer"

        />
        .....
    </q-header>

    <drawer-main :drawer="drawer"></drawer-main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DrawerMain from "@/components/drawer/DrawerMain";
export default {
  props: ["miniState", "drawerClick"],
  components: {
    DrawerMain
  },
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Child component :

```
<template>
  <q-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    show-if-above
    :mini="!drawer || miniState"
    @click.capture="drawerClick"
  >

    <div class="q-mini-drawer-hide absolute" style="top: 15px; right: -17px">
      <q-btn
        @click="miniState = true"
      />
    </div>
  </q-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import DrawerNavigation from "@/components/drawer/DrawerNavigation";
export default {
  props: ["drawer"],
  components: {
    DrawerNavigation
  },

  data() {
    return { miniState: false };
  },
  methods: {
    drawerClick(e) {
      if (this.miniState) {
        this.miniState = false;
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You should move `v-model="drawer"` into the parent component instead, and then read up on how to implement native events to the child components in this guide: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components. Alternatively, you can use [`v-bind.sync`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

Comment: It works, but it doesn't toggle the drawer all the way. I am using quasar framework: [quasar.dev/layout/drawer#Click-trigger](https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#Click-trigger)

Comment: can you create minimal example in codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

USe `v-bin.sync` as mentioned in the comment of @Terry or assign the prop value to a data attribute.

```
<template>
  <q-drawer
    v-model="internalDrawer"
    show-if-above
    :mini="!internalDrawer|| miniState"
    @click.capture="drawerClick"
  >

    <div class="q-mini-drawer-hide absolute" style="top: 15px; right: -17px">
      <q-btn
        @click="miniState = true"
      />
    </div>
  </q-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import DrawerNavigation from "@/components/drawer/DrawerNavigation";
export default {
  props: ["drawer"],
  components: {
    DrawerNavigation
  },

  data() {
    return { 
      miniState: false 
      internalDrawer: this.drawer
    };
  },
  methods: {
    drawerClick(e) {
      if (this.miniState) {
        this.miniState = false;
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The error is gone, but the drawer is not working properly.. when i click on the snackbar in the parent component, the drawer should be invisible from the DOM [drawer#Click-trigger](https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#Click-trigger)

Comment: It doesn't look the most efficient but you could watch the drawer and update the internalWatch with the same value

Comment: I have posted my answer, I'm not sure if that what you meant to say? but still there's one issue for me to fix..